# How do I capture the `id` of my child/nested (sub) tabs of my dojo TabContainer?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I have a set of tabs with child tabs. I need to get the `id` of each tab when it is clicked. I first found the `watch` function built into the `dojo` `TabContainer` object:

```
myTabContainer.watch("selectedChildWidget", function(name, oval, nval){
    console.log("selected child changed from ", oval, " to ", nval);
});
```

This works for parent tabs, but not for child/nested sub tabs. My only clue is that the child tabs are `ContentPane` objects and not `TabContainer` objects.

I also tried this, which also works only for parent tabs:

```
var tcmainid = tcmain.id;
dojo.connect(dijit.byId(tcmainid), "selectChild", function(page){console.log("Page ID: " + page.id)});
```

Here is my tab creation code:

```
var tcmain = new TabContainer({doLayout: false}, 'htmlDDIVid');

var parentTab1 = new ContentPane({title: "Tab1", content: gridx1});
var parentTab2 = new TabContainer({title: "Tab2", doLayout: false, nested: true});

var parentTab2SubTab1 = new ContentPane({title: "SubTab1", content: sub1Gridx});
var parentTab2SubTab2 = new ContentPane({title: "SubTab2", content: sub2Gridx});

parentTab2.addChild(parentTab2SubTab1);
parentTab2.addChild(parentTab2SubTab2);

tcmain.addChild(parentTab1);
tcmain.addChild(parentTab2);
```

How do I get the `id` for my child/nested sub tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I tried a couple of different methods but only this one worked for child tabs. Here is my solution:

Using:

```
"dijit/registry",
"dojo/on",
```

in my dojo `require` statement.

`myGridxID` is the `TabContainer` id that lives in my HTML page's DIV where my TabContainer is drawn that houses all my tabs and subtabs, with every leaf tab having a `gridx`.

```
// Pickup the onClick and get the ID of the tab or sub tab being clicked, this is used in the case switch statement for updating the grid accordingly
    var tabContainerPanel = registry.byId('myGridxID');   //get dijit from its source dom element

    on(tabContainerPanel, "Click", function (event) {
        selectedTabString = tabContainerPanel.selectedChildWidget.title;

        if (typeof tabContainerPanel.selectedChildWidget.selectedChildWidget !== 'undefined'){
            // There are no child tabs, parent tab only
            selectedTabString = tabContainerPanel.selectedChildWidget.selectedChildWidget.title;
        }
```

The issue I then ran into is that the clicks are picked up for the current tab inside the gridx. I'm bypassing this with an if statement:

```
if (selectedTabString !== prevSelectedTabString){
```

to check and see if the current `gridx` I am clicking on is the same as the one I had just selected and then it ignores the clicks or I should say ignores the code I have when a tab is clicked. When a tab is clicked in my code I have it update that tabs Gridx.